# installation bochs Compile Error x.cc:37:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zfl/bochs-2.6.9/gui'
g++ -c  -I.. -I./.. -I../iodev -I./../iodev -I../instrument/stubs -I./../instrument/stubs -g -O2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -pthread     x.cc -o x.o
x.cc:37:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [x.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zfl/bochs-2.6.9/gui'
make: *** [gui/libgui.a] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you are trying to do and what you did before getting the message above?  Did you download the software?  Were you trying to install with apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the [libx11](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libx11) package.

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

and recompile after that.

EDIT:
Steps to recompile. Run the following commands.

1. `make dist-clean`
2. `./configure`
3. `make`